# Show that a $\{x_n\}$ is Cauchy

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $|x_n-x_k| < \frac n{k^2}$ for all $n,k\in\Bbb N$.
Show that $\{x_n\}$ is Cauchy.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! What have you tried?

Comment: Since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Given $\epsilon>0$, there exist $N$ with $\frac 1N<\epsilon$. Use the given condition to show that $|x_n-x_m|<\epsilon$ for all $n,m>N$.